# How to put a menu bar in my media query of max-width=1000px in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I'm having problems putting a menu tag on my website. I have watched so many videos on it but all to no avail.  The media query is this:

```
media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  /*CSS code here.*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one key feature, the '@' sign before the word media. The correct media query would be:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) { /*CSS code here.*/}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Can you help me with the code on how to build it. I need the full code.